# Consuming .net WCF service from Java

Tags: java, wcf, intellij-idea, jax-ws

I new to Java, and thought it'd be a nice learning exercise to implement a client application on top of a .NET WCF service I'm already familiar with.

I ran wsimport.bat from the latest JAX-WS (https://jax-ws.java.net/) to generate the client proxies, However I'm stuck with the authentication part. The WCF service uses Application level Username/Password to authenticate. I don't know where to supply the credentials.

In C#, for this WCF Service I just need to add a service reference, and do the following:

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
client.DoSomething();
```

From Fiddler, calling client.DoSomething() produces the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2013-05-20T01:34:28.353Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2013-05-20T01:39:28.353Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-da5b7b57-dbb4-4c54-b529-f5b41fc728b4-1">
        <o:Username>username</o:Username>
        <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <DoSomething xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is the Java I'm currently using:

```
SomeService service = new SomeService();
ISomeService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingISomeService();
DoSomethingResponse response = port.getDoSomething();
```

This produces the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns6:DoSomething xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns6="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

It's missing the Security node, so I'm not sure how to set that up on the Java side. What am I missing?

I'm not 100% bound to using JAX-WS, if there is a better alternative out there for my needs. However, the WCF service can not be modified to reconfigured, as it's out of my reach.

WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="SomeService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Lax/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
        <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:UsernameToken>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
        <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy/>
        </sp:Wss10>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://someservice.com/service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://someservice.com/service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://someservice.com/service.svc?xsd=xsd6" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ISomeService_DoSomething_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DoSomethingResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ISomeService">
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISomeService/DoSomething" message="tns:ISomeService_DoSomething_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISomeService/DoSomethingResponse" message="tns:ISomeService_DoSomething_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" type="tns:ISomeService">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService_policy"/>
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="DoSomething">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISomeService/DoSomething" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SomeService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService">
      <soap:address location="https://someservice.com/service.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm using the latest JDK on Windows 8 x64

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue at the moment (the security policy in the wsdl is exactly the same as the one I'm connecting to) - did you ever figure out a solution for adding the security node? I've tried adding a callbackhandler to my code but to be honest wasn't too sure what I was doing and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom CallbackHandler from your Java client. I am not an expert in Java but I know that some of my clients use Metro libraries to communicate with my WCF web services.

Try searching for creating a CallbackHandler with/without Metro library.

You can download [Metro library](https://metro.java.net/) from here.

[An example](http://blog.csdn.net/marvion/article/details/4015785) of what I am suggesting.