# Java- Invoke .net wcf web service Spring

Tags: java, asp.net, spring, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created spring rest controller. In that i need use *.net* wcf service inside rest controller. Is it possible to consume *.net wcf web service* in java application? If it's possible, could you please explain me how to consume wcf service in java

> Note: .net wcf service hosted in remote server

Comment: web service mean you can consume it by any other platform !

Comment: ya but how can we consume it .it's mean what a way i can use this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming .net WCF service from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656818/consuming-net-wcf-service-from-java)

Comment: now me able to access some wcf method but some method it changed argument type

Answer (score 1):

As wcf web service is just another web service so we can consume web service easily using RestTemplate of Spring. If your web service is based on GET method of HTTP than you can call that in your spring rest controller as in the following code:

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);

Here Quote is pojo class you can create to store the response of the wcf web service.

Comment: if i trying to add this above code i am getting this error Quote cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to create new pojo class Quote. https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/ here you can see the complete example.